# How to change url path to name in django instead of id

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

sorry if I ask very a simple question, I'm just starting to learn about WebDev and I have a question about django url and I used rest framework. I have http://localhost:8000/api/projectList/1 and I want to change id to the name in the url, for example http://localhost:8000/api/projectList/project
This is the code:

model.py

```
 class ProjectList(models.Model):
   project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   academic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

view.py

```
class ProjectListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta :
        model = ProjectList
        fields = '__all__'

class ProjectListViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProjectList.objects.all()
    serializers_class = ProjectListSerializer

class ProjectListListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProjectListSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProjectList.objects.all()

class ProjectId(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ProjectList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectListSerializer
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
    path("projectList/", ProjectListListView.as_view()),
    path("projectList/<int:pk>", ProjectId.as_view()),
]
```

Thank you, sorry for my simple question and my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views and serializer define lookup_field = project, this will override the default id field.

Ps - make sure project is unique and primary key.

also change your url to accept string instead of int(id)

Comment: It works! but except the name with id = 1, maybe that's because it's not unique and primary key?

Comment: didn't get you? can you explain ?

Comment: if project name is not uniques how will the handler decide which object to show.

Comment: well you can also google it to know more details about lookup_field.

Comment: I've tried what you answered and changed url to `path("projectList/<str:project>", ProjectId.as_view())` it works for some /names but except the name which id is 1 it just displayed error page (404 not found). I'm very sorry for my bad english

Comment: make your project in model as unique=True, it is not good way to look for fields that are not unique. and also I will recommend not to change the default id.  Find ways where you can access data based on id.

Comment: if you have just started, there may be times where project can be same (suppose a situation) you will have to deal with id.

Answer (score 1):

Django Rest Framework ModelViewset doesn't require to declare separate view for detail. In ProjectListListView declare

```
lookup_field = 'project'
```

and delete

```
path("projectList/<int:pk>", ProjectId.as_view()),
```

from urlpatterns